# Why is this multi-value data structure not working?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm learning about Python data structures, and am looking at this code:

```
class Student:
    firstname=""
    lastname=""
    grade="U"
    list=[]


student=Student()#create the student
student.firstname=str(input("Input student first name: "))
list.append(student.firstname)
student.lastname=str(input("Input student last name: "))
list.append(student.lastname)
student.grade=str(input("Input student grade: "))
list.append(student.grade)

#print the student data
print("First Name: " + student.firstname)
print("Last Name: " + student.lastname)
print("Grade: " + student.grade)
```

After the first input for `student.firstname`, it just says there's an error (`TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object`)

What's wrong? I thought the code would just add the firstname to the end of the list, right?

Comment: First you should consider using https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html and be careful as you are using a python keyword as an attribute (`list` change this maybe)

Answer (score 0):

The name `list` refers to the built-in type. `list.append` is an unbound method of that type, and has nothing to do with the class attribute named `list` associated with the class `Student`.

It would "work" if you passed the appropriate list as the first argument (for reasons I won't get into here)

```
list.append(student.list, student.firstname)
```

but you should *really* be defining additional methods for the class, in addition to the `__init__` method that should define the attributes in the first place.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, grade):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.grade = "U"

x = input("Input student first name: ")
y = input("Input student last name: ")
z = input("Input student grade: ")

student = Student(x, y, z)
print("First Name: " + student.firstname)
print("Last Name: " + student.lastname)
print("Grade: " + student.grade)
```

It's not clear what the purpose of the list is, anyway. Do you want to keep a list of instances of `Student`, perhaps? Do that outside the class. For example,

```
students = []
student = Student("John", "Doe", "U")
students.append(student)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list=[]` and `list.append(student.firstname)` are one problem: `list` is a `type`, not an appropriate object name

I'd recommend [backing up to basics](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) and implementing:

- creation of your class instances with (e.g.) `def __init__(self, first, last, grade)`
- definition of `__str__(self)` to define how to `print()` your objects
- define a `list`, e.g. `allStudents = []`
- add students to it `allStudents.append(Student(first, last, grade))`

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp